# How can I change the author email in git commit history which has been pushed, and what shall I be careful for?

Tags: git

I've read some articles about this topic. Some of them say that I should use, for example **interactive rebase** only on local commits. Others say that "take care when using it on a branch that has already been pushed", but what do I need to take care?

**Background of my problem:**

- My team (less than 10 people, about 2 commits per day) is working on a large Git repo, to which lots of teams push changes.
- We have our own branch (let's say team_branch_a), to which we can push almost any code, but eventually we have to push our code to master.
- A sanity pipeline job runs on every commit to any branch. We can still push code to our own branch (team_branch_a) normally even if the sanity is failed, but we cannot merge our branch to master unless the sanity job is passed.
- The sanity fails if e-mail of a Git commit is invalid.

**My problem is:**

- One of my team member pushed a commit with invalid author e-mail by accident to our own branch (team_branch_a).
- He didn't notice the issue until several commits were made.
- In the mean time, other commits were pushed to our own branch (team_branch_a). Other people in my team also merged the branch with invalid author history.
- When the team eventually noticed that problem, we have a commit history of approximately 20 commits from the first commit with invalid author e-mail, 8 of them have invalid e-mail, and 5 of them are merges (to branch team_branch_a), and the remaining are normal commits.

We have met the issues of sanity failure before, but all of them are code issue, for example too long code lines, redundant blank line, etc. We can resolve it by just pushing a new commit. But this time even we push a new commit with correct e-mail, the history issue is still there.

One simple solution is that I abandon my current branch by creating a new branch (let's say team_branch_b) from the commit immediately before the fist commit with invalid author e-mail, and copy/paste the latest code from the old branch (team_branch_a) and commit to team_branch_b, then merge team_branch_b to master (and abandon team_branch_a). The disadvantage is that it loses commit history.

But I wonder if there is a better way to do this, especially a way that can keep these 20 commits and merge history. When someone was talking about "interactive rebase", which can resolve this problem, with detailed steps, they say that "take care when using it on a branch that has already been pushed", but what shall I take care?

Assume that I have full control of my team, for example I can ask them to not push or pull any code when I'm resolving the problem, then ask all of them to pull the latest code after the issue is resolved, or even ask them to remove the cloned copy and clone the repo again.

So, what can I do to amend the author e-mail to the pushed commits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have read, if you want to fix this, you have to rewrite the history. I won't go into details about that since you say you already found that information. I want to focus on what "take care" is referring to.

What you need to take care of, primarily, is making sure only the new history is used after you rewrite it. If someone has work started from the old history, they'll need to rebase it or cherry-pick it onto the new, rewritten history.

So the process would be:

- tell all contributors you're about to rewrite history and hold off on any pushes, maybe even commits,
- do your history rewriting and force push it,
- and then tell all contributors to make sure all future work starts from the new history.

By "all contributors", here, I mean the team that's working on the branch you want to rewrite, so that's only the small set of people working on `team_branch_a` in your scenario, not necessarily everyone using the repo.

After you pushed the rewritten history, what you contributors need to do is:

- Just start any new work from the new history - that's the easy option.
- If they have previously started work from the old history, ask them to rebase that work onto the new history, or to cherry-pick the relevant commits onto a new branch, and carefully look at their commit history before pushing, to make sure they're not pushing the old commits back in.

If anyone is careless, you might end up with a merge that brings the old history back in, and then you would have duplicated commits with the same changes, one set from the commit with the wrong e-mail address, and a second second from the fixed commit.

Comment: Actually I asked them to commit and push all their local changes, then I did the interactive rebase and pushed the change with -f flag. Then I asked them to switch to branch team_branch_a, fetch, then git reset origin/team_branch_a --hard. The issue was resolved.